# java cannot find symbol 'readLine'

Tags: java, сеть, java-util-logger

IDE не запускает программу из-за этого участка кода не пропуская его

```
 String str = in.readLine();
```

Пишет cannot find symbol 'readLine' и всё, решения на alt+Enter не помогает и выводит ту же ошибку 
Вот весь код

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package client;

import console_chat.Const;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author kernozz
 */
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Введите IP для подключения к серверу."); 
    System.out.println("Формат: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"); 

    String ip = scan.nextLine(); 
    Socket socket = new Socket(ip, Const.Port); 
    try{ 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    System.out.println("Введите свой ник:"); 
    out.println(scan.nextLine()); 
    String str = ""; 
        while (!str.equals("exit")) { 
            str = scan.nextLine(); 
            out.println(str); 
        } 
    }
private class Resender extends Thread { 
    private boolean stoped; 

    public void setStop() { 
        stoped = true; 
    } 
     @Override 
    public void run() { 
        try { 
            while (!stoped) { 
                String str = in.readLine(); 
                System.out.println(str); 
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            System.err.println("Ошибка при получении сообщения."); 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А с чего вы взяли, что у [java.lang.System.in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) есть метод readLine()?

Используйте обертки, которые могут это делать: [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) + [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

```
BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line=buffer.readLine();
```

Можно еще использовать [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = scanner.nextLine();
```